# Change the "selected value" of a dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have product Category dropdown which is one of the items about a product which I display.

```
Product Category:
<label class="ff" for="f"><em>*</em></label>
<div class="sort-options-wrapper" id="f" >
    <select class="sort-options" id="sortOptions" 
    onchange="SelectedValueF(this)">
    </select>
</div>
```

The dropdown is loaded at document ready and the selected item defaults to the first prod cat in the list. I then load a product record from the DB and it contains a prod cat. I want to set the "selected item" in the dropdown to the one retrieved from the DB record. I have tried lots of suggestions found in the stackoverflow archives but none work for me. Also, I'm a bit new JavaScript, J Query, Ajax, etc but I'm trying.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: jQuery's `.val` on the `<select>` should help.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mcve]. _“I have tried lots of suggestions found in the stackoverflow archives but none work for me”_ - you need to _show us_ what you tried.

Comment: your problem statement is not clear, what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set:

```
document.getElementById("sortOptions").value = "your_value";
```

and `(onchange)=this.value`

```js
function SelectedValueF(val)
{
  console.log(val);
  document.getElementById("sortOptions").value = "C";
}
```

```html
Product Category:
<label class="ff" for="f"><em>*</em></label>
<div class="sort-options-wrapper" id="f" >
    <select class="sort-options" id="sortOptions" 
    onchange="SelectedValueF(this.value)">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It has been said that my problem statement is unclear. At my knowledge level, I do have trouble with appropriate terminology. The dropdown text contains the prodcat description and value contains its prodcatID - a number unrelated to it's position in the list - and at onclick, I can establish what each of these is. My problem is setting the selected value/text pair to what I find in the record retrieved from the DB. Your code works if I use value (prodcatID)  instead of text and the prodcat description appears in the selected box (I don't know what to call that "box").

Comment: @user2365040 Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Nested `<option>` tags should have attribute 'value' equal to your selection options. Then you simply do `$('#sortOptions').val(optionValue)`

Following sample demonstrates random option selection

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  let options = ['a','b','c','d'];
  $('#optionSelect').val(options[Math.floor(Math.random()*(options.length))]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="optionSelect">
<option value='a'>a</option>
<option value='b'>b</option>
<option value='c'>c</option>
<option value='d'>d</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Apologies, but I couldn't get this to run and my knowledge level is insufficient to understand the code.